# How to combine every two adjoining lines in Chinese txt file into one line with Python

Tags: python

I have a Chinese txt file with thousands of sentence lines as following,

1. line 1
2. line 2
3. line 3
4. line 4

…………

I want to combine every two adjoining lines into one line,it should be transformed as:

1. line 1 + space + line 2
2. line 3 + space + line 4
3. line 5 + space + line 6
   …………

How can I use Python to finish the combination?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Python for that, `sed` is enough:

```
$ seq 15 > lines
$ cat lines
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
$ sed 'N;s/\n/ /g' lines
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
11 12
13 14
15
```

According to man sed:

> n N    Read/append the next line of input into the pattern space.

and

> s/regexp/replacement/
>
> Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If successful, replace that portion matched with replacement.  The replacement may contain the special  character  &  to refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched, and the special escapes \1 through \9 to refer to the corresponding matching sub-expressions in the regexp.

And, as `sed` execute the given script for each line, the newline character is not included in the pattern space (it would be redundant to include it). So the executed sequence is:

- sed loads a line in the pattern space
- `N`: Append the next line to the pattern space, now that we have two lines in the pattern space, they have to be separated by a newline, so we have a newline character in the middle of the pattern space
- `s/\n/ /` replace the newline character by a space
- sed now print the line as there's nothing more to do on this line
- And starts again with the next line

Comment: According to `man sed | grep 'N  '`, `N` append the next line of input into the pattern space. So for each line, you're appending the next line, replacing the newline between them with a space, and again reading a line, appending another, replacing the newline...

Answer (score 0):

1. You would read the file and obtain a list of lines (i.e. list of strings)
2. then you could use a list comprehension, like this one:

   `[ l1 + ' ' + l2 for l1,l2 in zip(lines[::2], lines[1::2]) ]`

Note, this means you'll have to have an equal number of lines. so if `len(lines)%2==1` then use `lines[-1]` to print out/use the last line by itself

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate on your file like follows:

```
with open('./chinese.txt') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        try:
            print '{} {}'.format(line.strip(), my_file.next())
        except StopIteration:  # Manage case: number of lines is an odd number
            print line
```

Answer (score 0):

A file is an iterator over lines in Python. You could [use the itertools' grouper() recipe, to group the lines into pairs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from itertools import izip_longest

with open('Chinese.txt') as file:
    for line, another in izip_longest(file, file, fillvalue=''):
        print line.rstrip('\n'), another,
```

The comma at the end of the `print` statement is [the `file.softspace` hack, to avoid duplicating newlines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.softspace).

The code keeps only two lines in the memory and therefore it can support arbitrary large files.